# JPA Criteria API recursive fetch lazy association

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, hibernate-criteria

I have a recursive entity which has an association with itself.

```
@Entity
public class Function {
    (...)

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Set<Function> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

If this association would be eager `@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)`, then all of its children would always be initialized with one trip to the database. Of course, I don't want this association to be eager.

With the JPA Criteria API, one could fetch a collection with `someRoot.fetch(Function_.children)`. This only fetches it one level deep though and is not recursive like the eager fetch type.

Is there a way to recursively fetch its children without making it an eager association?

Comment: Either you want it lazy or eager there is no 3rd type of eager-on-lazy-init

Comment: @XtremeBaumer It's not configured it, so it's still on its default value. How would this help me?

Comment: If you access the "second" layer, what exactly happens? it should still hydrate the entities

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Yes it will, but I'm trying to avoid an extra database call.

Answer (score 0):

I've opted to go for multiple mappings for the same table. There's some dangers in this, but since the entities are short lived and only one of them needs to be writable, it's fine.

In my case, one of them doesn't even need to access its children, further simplifying my this entity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class BaseFunction {
    (...)
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "function")
public class RecursiveFunction extends BaseFunction {

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<RecursiveFunction> children = new HashSet<>();
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "function")
public class SimpleFunction extends BaseFunction {}
```